# How to run jupyter-notebook without sudo?

Tags: python, jupyter

I can't run jupyter-notebook without using *sudo*. 
When trying to do this I get:

```html
[E 20:54:49.571 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /tree?token=7037406b1f5eafad97b53dfa9d12677d2b10ff0fb49a5669 (127.0.0.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/tree?token=7037406b1f5eafad97b53dfa9d12677d2b10ff0fb49a5669', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,uk;q=0.4', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br', 'Host': 'localhost:8888', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cookie': 'org.cups.sid=2d9b3d25b9989a22df29dad8659dcb56; user-id=illia|Sat%2C%2004%20Mar%202017%2000%3A55%3A59%20GMT|z7CyGKY3cXs10M9PDt3%2B2SlZD%2BkYbX18pe7q5TtuHq8%3D; csrf-token=a063b27d-be4f-4fbb-95cf-365415e05ef0; _xsrf=2|3d79f079|96e5c72e5b6de7d496e5f331b0fb4a92|1491469477; username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1492962420|23:username-localhost-8888|44:YjQ4NTBkNDYyYmMxNGFiMzg3YjY2NDQyNGJhYzkyZDU=|ebcc80ce525febfa49bdc81b9433ebe28f03511f21401304980ba4c8056f6733"', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1467, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2829, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/tree/handlers.py", line 50, in get
        terminals_available=self.settings['terminals_available'],
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 343, in render_template
        template = self.get_template(name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 339, in get_template
        return self.settings['jinja2_env'].get_template(name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
        return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
        template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
        source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 171, in get_source
        f = open_if_exists(filename)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 154, in open_if_exists
        return open(filename, mode)
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/home/illia/.local/share/jupyter/templates/tree.html'
[E 20:54:49.632 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in write_error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 994, in send_error
        self.write_error(status_code, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 410, in write_error
        html = self.render_template('%s.html' % status_code, **ns)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 343, in render_template
        template = self.get_template(name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 339, in get_template
        return self.settings['jinja2_env'].get_template(name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
        return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
        template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
        source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 171, in get_source
        f = open_if_exists(filename)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 154, in open_if_exists
        return open(filename, mode)
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/home/illia/.local/share/jupyter/templates/500.html'
```

What could be the source of the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: How did you install `jupyter`?

Comment: edwinksl, using pip.

Comment: Maybe, the problem is that I installed it with root permissions, but in fact, I cannot use *pip install* without *sudo*.